# Contacts and Phone icons missing

Tags: contacts, home-screen-shortcuts

My Contacts and Phone icons are missing from my primary shortcuts bar. I can't restore from the Edit in the app drawer since they don't show there. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

(Samsung Galaxy Note)

Comment: Rooted? Custom ROM?

Comment: "Contacts" may instead be "People".

Answer (score 4):

Same happened to me on my NOTE 3, and what I found was I had inadvertently TURNED OFF the CONTACTS app.

On Samsung phones go to Settings, General tab, Application Manager scroll to the last page labeled "TURNED OFF". Click on the app you need to turn on and select Turn On.

That did it for me.

Comment: I wish I had found that earlier. Well done! :)

Answer (score 2):

In your app drawer (the main one), you should see them. You can then long press and drag them to the main bar at the bottom.

Comment: thanks for the reply but this is the problem: neither Contacts nor Phone icon shows in my app drawer.

Comment: @preston In *any* app drawer? Please reboot, and check again. Did it come with these apps? Is it a phone or tablet?

Comment: its a galaxy note running stock ICS, rebooted, they are still missing. In your first reply u said 'the mail one', did u mean 'main one'?

Comment: I tried to restore them via the blue Applications button, Edit (in grid view), then drag and drop. Works fine with other apps but Contacts and Phone don't show there.

Comment: But can you see Contacts and Phone anywhere else? If so, just drap and drop - no need to enter edit mode (long press on icon).

Comment: @preston: That's all important information you should add to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting your launcher data from settings:

`Settings` → `Apps` → `Launcher` → `Clear Data`

Comment: Could you elaborate on why this would help?

Answer (score 0):

Some apps show in the play store but nowhere on your phone.  In that case you can go to the play store and open you installed apps area.  Locate the app that is missing and click to uninstall it.  You will most likely be uninstalling the update that cause the problem.   Make sure the app is still install and saying to install uupdate and then reboot the phone.  Once the phone is back on you should be able to locate the missing app.  Also check the status of the app in the play store.  The update may not be needed at this time.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to go to the settings>all apps>contacts>uninstall updates.
contacts are gonna reappear.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be with the contacts default contacts App itself. I simply downloaded another contacts App from Playstore and all my contacts came back through it

Answer (score -1):

Go to `Settings` → `Apps` → `All` → `Phone` and press the `Force to Stop` button. Phone now will appear